# How to prove this general result on tucker circle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $X_1$ be an arbitrary point on side $AB$ of $∆ABC$ as shown in

[image]

[Figure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4xkpa1jc1434l3/1637004167055.png?dl=0)

Let $L_1$ be the line passing through $X_1$ perpendicular to $AB$.

Let $L_1$  cut $AC$ at $X_2$.

Let us define another line $L_2$ passing through $X_2$ parallel to $AB$.

$L_2$ cuts $BC$ at $X_3$.

Let $L_3$ be the line passing through $X_3$ and perpendicular to $L_2$.

line $L_3$ cuts $AB$ at $X_4$ then $X_1X_2X_3X_4$ becomes a rectangle!

Drop perpendicular from $X_1$ on $BC$ at $X_5$ and
Drop perpendicular from $X_4$ on $AC$ at $X_6$.
Then the 6 points $\{X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6 \}$ lie on a same circle.

Comment: You should give a reference such as [this one](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/TuckerCircle.shtml#explanation) to recall what a Tucker circle is...

Comment: Sorry, next time I remember this thing

Comment: I have included your figure and attempted to better your text. For next time, indices are created in Latex like  this: `$A_1, A_2$` (don't forget to enclose mathematical expressions between dollar signs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are definitely cyclic.

Next,  show that $X_1, X_4, X_2, X_6$ are cyclic.

Do the same thing to $X_1, X_4, X_5, X_3$.

Comment: Yes, angle (X6X2X1)=angle (X6X4X1) and using the statement "when angle on the same segment are equal then 4 points will be concylcic" , we able to get the results.